# What is the subject of "get the wrong idea" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, parallelism

[image: wimpy kid]

What is the subject of "get the wrong idea"?

Please explain the meaning of "get the wrong idea."

This book is "Diary of a Wimpy Kid" by Jeff Kinney.

Comment: In what way do you want the sentence to be changed? That is not clear. Also, when you post something from a book, best practice is to say what the book is and who wrote it. (I know this is from one of the Diary of a Wimpy Kid books because I work with children.)

Comment: @KatherineLockwood thanks for your feedback. I edited.

Comment: Good edit--makes it much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

"Some jerk" is the one who might get the wrong idea, and therefore the subject. The sentence means that the writer is worried that a mean person will see him carrying the book, and by seeing him with the book, form an incorrect idea about something.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to understand if we put a portion of the sentence in brackets:

> Great. All I need is for some jerk to catch me [carrying this book around] and get the wrong idea.

In other words, the "jerk" catches him and gets the wrong idea either *about the book* or *about him because he's carrying the book*.

Answer (score -1):

As i know, to *get the wrong idea* means:

> "to think that something is true when it is not"

The wrong idea here is: Greg keeps a diary because he is an emotional person, maybe with not many friends and he is "weak" (this is why he is wimpy). The "correct" idea is that Greg keeps a "journal".

P.S. English is not my first Language